# Launch Visual Studio 2010 with new document?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to launch Visual Studio 2010 with a new document instead of the usual start tab?

I'm just curious--I usually use Notepad++ to jot down quick things, but Visual Studio seems like it would be preferable.

Comment: Hai guise what's going on in here?

Answer (score 1):

[Here are your choices.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165469.aspx)

Curious, though, as to why you would want to open a full-fledged IDE just to take notes. That seems like precisely the kind of thing a *notepad* application is suited for...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shortcut that always launches a specific file, e.g.:

1. Put a document called "notes.txt" on your desktop.
2. Copy the Visual Studio 2010 shortcut to your desktop (to a new shortcut)
3. Edit the shortcut properties (right click → properties → Shortcut tab → Target) to add this to the end of the Target:

> /edit "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\notes.txt"